# Nested while loop on dataframe - Redefining column

Tags: python, dataframe, while-loop, nested

Defining colum in Dataframe through nested loops

I need to pick rows of values from a dataframe [Assets] until the values meet a pre-defined sum. I have already sorted the dataframe according to the priority in which I need to pick rows. Also I have done an additional column [ACC_VALUE] accumulating according to the relevant value column. Rows that are to be included should be given the column [Picked] = 'Y'.

I have writen the following code which does not work:

```
#Default = N
Assets['Picked'] = 'N'

#Threshold_sum to be reached
Threshold_sum  = 1000000

for row in Assets.iterrows():
     while Assets['ACC_VALUE'] < Threshold_sum:
          Assets['Picked'] = 'Y'
```

Sorry, I know that I am off on the Python syntax here. I am new to while and for loops. Please can you help me out? Thanks!

Comment: why not `Assets['Picked'][ Assets['ACC_VALUE'] < Threshold_sum ] = 'Y'`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show example data and expected result but I think you don't need loop but directly

```
Assets['Picked'] = 'N'

mask = (Assets['ACC_VALUE'] < threshold_sum)

Assets.loc[mask,'Picked'] = 'Y'
```

---

Minimal working example

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [1,2,3,4,5], 
})

df['Picked'] = 'N'
df['ACC_VALUE'] = df['A'].cumsum()

print('\n--- before ---\n')
print(df)

threshold_sum  = 10
mask = (df['ACC_VALUE'] < threshold_sum)
df.loc[mask,'Picked'] = 'Y'

print('\n--- after ---\n')
print(df)
```

Result:

```
--- before ---

   A Picked  ACC_VALUE
0  1      N          1
1  2      N          3
2  3      N          6
3  4      N         10
4  5      N         15

--- after ---

   A Picked  ACC_VALUE
0  1      Y          1
1  2      Y          3
2  3      Y          6
3  4      N         10
4  5      N         15
```

---

**EDIT:**

You could also directly create new column `'Picked'`

using `.apply()`

```
df['Picked'] = df['ACC_VALUE'].apply(lambda val: 'Y' if val < threshold_sum else 'N')
```

or `.map()`

```
df['Picked'] = df['ACC_VALUE'].map(lambda val: 'Y' if val < threshold_sum else 'N')
```

or `numpy.where()`

```
import numpy as np

df['Picked'] = np.where(df['ACC_VALUE'] < threshold_sum, 'Y', 'N')
```

Comment: Thank you so much furas! Of course, this seems so obvious now. Somehow the while loop idea was stuck in my head. Again, thanks a lot!